# Retweets of retweets, and what happens when they are undone

Tags: twitter, tweet, retweet

I have a question about retweets on Twitter. Imagine Bob posts a tweet. Then Sue retweets the message. Finally, Sara retweets Sue's retweet. What happens to Sara's retweet if Sue "undoes" her retweet? Does Sara's go away as well, because she RTed from Sue? Or, because the Tweet still remains, does Sara's RT stay?

Answer (score 1):

Sara's retweet stays. Although Sue's notification says "Sara Retweeted your Retweet", on Sara's timeline you will see the retweet directly linked to the original Bob's tweet, not passing through Sue. Whatever Sue does will not affect this RT.

I confirmed this experimentally. [This tweet](https://twitter.com/NormalHumanChat/status/691977152221286400) was retweeted by [@NormalHumanSE](https://twitter.com/NormalHumanSE) and that retweet was retweeted by [@Shog9](https://twitter.com/Shog9). I then undid the retweet by [@NormalHumanSE](https://twitter.com/NormalHumanSE) and observed that (as you can see) it remains on [@Shog9](https://twitter.com/Shog9)'s timeline.